# convert & save text to speech file

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech

I am using this code to convert & save text to speech using 
****using System.Speech.Synthesis;****
but it throws -
asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event.
this is my code:

```
using (Stream ret = new MemoryStream())
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            var mi = synth.GetType().GetMethod("SetOutputStream", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var fmt = new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(8000, AudioBitsPerSample.Eight, AudioChannel.Mono);
            mi.Invoke(synth, new object[] { ret, fmt, true, true });
            synth.Speak("Greetings from stack overflow");
            // Testing code:
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.wav", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                ret.Position = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                for (; ; )
                {
                    int len = ret.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (len == 0) break;
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where in the asp.net page lifecycle are you doing this?

Comment: i use this for convert text files,.......

Comment: That's not what I asked; I understand what you are doing, but where in the page lifecycle is this happening, page load, init, prerender, render??

Comment: this is happaning in prerender stage  .......... can you help me to solve this error.? i doesn't know what to do for this.......

Comment: Try putting the code in Load event and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: ha i use that code into page load but it shows same error....

Comment: visual studio trows target invocation exception in 5th line of code..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Visual Studio isn't throwing any exceptions. .NET is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

add this into page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext =
        new System.Threading.SynchronizationContext();
}
```

Comment: Please explain how and why that helps.